# Apache + PHPMyAdmin - Redirect directory to subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, phpmyadmin

So im running Apache on Ubuntu 16. I have phpmyadmin accessible via a directory because thats how it does it by default (e.g. to access phpmyadmin, I have to go to www.mydomain.com/phpmyadmin)

I wrote an Apache VHost to make it accessible via a subdomain as shown here in my Vhosts:
http://pastebin.com/raw/tyZGbsSC

This works and now I can access phpmyadmin via a subdomain (phpmyadmin.mydomain.com) but the problem is that it is still accessible through the directory (www.mydomain.com/phpmyadmin)

How to i stop this?

Comment: Have you tried to write an .htaccess rule that sends www.mydomain.com/phpmyadmin to a 404 error page? Something like: RewriteRule ^phpmyadmin/ - [L,R = 404]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a conf file `phpmyadmin.conf` in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled` which contains the following line

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Just comment out that line by putting a hash

```
#Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

and restart apache.

That should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the server-wide configuration enabled in /etc/apache2/conf-enabled

```
user@host:~ $ sudo a2disconf phpmyadmin
```

should disable it for you, or just remove /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf